# Data::Dumper Perl module

Tags: perl, perl-module, data-dumper

What does the following statement actually mean?

```
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
```

Is `Data::Dumper` only used for printing contents of a hash?

Could you please explain in brief?

Answer (score 3):

In simple words, [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) takes a Perl data structure and turns it into a string containing Perl code that, when [eval()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)ed (that is, run as code), returns an equivalent data structure. This is useful for many reasons, but a very simple use is to print out a data-structure to see if it matches what you think it is.

Example:

```
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); # Import the Dumper() subroutine
my %hash = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 );
print Dumper(\%hash);  # Note the \ backslash; Dumper() takes references as arguments
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => 3,
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => 2
        };
```

It is taken from *[Re: Data::Dumper in reference to Hashes](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=596909)*.

Answer (score 1):

The specific statement `use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper)` means "include the Dumper list of features from the Data::Dumper module in the namespace of this script."

The documentation for Data::Dumper says:

"Given a list of scalars or reference variables, writes out their contents in perl syntax."

This is useful, because then you can load them back into another script at another time and rely on Perl itself to parse the text correctly into the perl structures you had before.

Comment: is Dumper means that to dump the Perl code where we want to use it.

Comment: You could say that "Dumper" means "a routine to dump perl code of a list of objects into text", yes.

Answer (score 0):

Dumper method takes a list of scalar or reference ... reference can be from different type hashref, arrayref

It is a nice way for debugging complex structure

**SCALAR (not really useful indeed)**

```
[~]=> perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; $a=1; print Dumper($a);'
$VAR1 = 1;
```

**ARRAYREF**

```
[~]=> perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; @a=(1,2,3,4); print Dumper(\@a);'
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
        ];
```

**HASHREF**

```
[~]=> perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; %a=(a=>1,b=>2,c=>3); print Dumper(\%a);'
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 1,
          'c' => 3,
          'b' => 2
        };
```

**COMPLEX HASHREF**

```
[~]=> perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; %a=(a=>1,b=> ["apple","banana","pear"],c=> {z=>99,y=>98}); print Dumper(\%a);'
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => {
                   'z' => 99,
                   'y' => 98
                 },
          'b' => [
                   'apple',
                   'banana',
                   'pear'
                 ],
          'a' => 1
        };
```

**ARRAYREF and HASHREF**

```
[~]=> perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; @a=("zidane", "platini", "kopa"); %b=(a=>1,b=>2,c=>3); print Dumper(\@a, \%b);'
$VAR1 = [
          'zidane',
          'platini',
          'kopa'
        ];
$VAR2 = {
          'a' => 1,
          'c' => 3,
          'b' => 2
        };
```

**ARRAYREF with cycle**

```
[~]=> perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; %a=(x=>1, y=>\%a);  print Dumper(\%a);'
$VAR1 = {
          'x' => 1,
          'y' => $VAR1
        };
```